# Puppeteer - (Page.navigate): Target closed in https websites

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

As in title, i can't make puppeteer work with any `https` website, a simple code to demonstrate:

```
const run = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'], ignoreHTTPSErrors: true });
    const page = await browser.newPage()

    await page.setRequestInterception(true)
    page.on('request', (req) => {
        if (['stylesheet', 'font', 'image'].includes(req.resourceType())) req.abort()
        else req.continue()
    })

    await page.goto(`https://httpbin.org/`, {waitUntil:'networkidle2'})
    
    const content = await page.content()
    console.log(content)

    await browser.close()
}

run().catch(console.error)
```

```
ProtocolError: Protocol error (Page.navigate): Target closed.
    at /home/dev-a/apps/protocol/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:329:24
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at CDPSessionImpl.send (/home/dev-a/apps/protocol/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:325:16)
    at navigate (/home/dev-a/apps/protocol/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Frame.js:228:47)
    at Frame.goto (/home/dev-a/apps/protocol/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Frame.js:206:13)
    at Page.goto (/home/dev-a/apps/protocol/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Page.js:1165:88)
    at run (/home/dev-a/apps/protocol/tests.js:42:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  originalMessage: ''
}
```

If i run the same code, changing only the url to `http://httpbin.org/`, i get the results with no problem.

Btw, this happen only on my production ubuntu server (no gui).

lsb_release -a:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by installing chromium-browser and setting the `executablePath` on browser launch.

`sudo apt install chromium-browser -y`